# Radix Sort Time

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, radix-sort

I'm studying for a test that I have this week and I came across a review question that asks...

Twenty million positive integers in the range 0 . . . 99,999,999 are to be sorted by LSD radix sort.  Compare the performance for using radix 0 . . . 9999 and radix 0 . . . 9.  Show your
work.

I know that the time for a radix sort is theta(d(k+n)); where d = number of digits k= size of radix and n =number of records.

I understand the decimal radix would be theta(8(10+20,000,000)),correct?

What would the thousands radix be? theta(3(1000+20,000,000))?

Comment: Count your digits, it's not a thousands radix.

Comment: So should it be theta(2(10000+20,000,000))? What would that radix be called?

Comment: Myrias, if you want to brag with a bit of greek. Or ten-thousand, if you want to be understood.

Comment: So I can say that using the ten-thousand radix is about 4x as fast as using the decimal radix?

Comment: Seems so (for large enough data samples). The actual relation can be different though, due to implementation details, cache locality...

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the runtime is O(d(n + k)). It might help to explicitly work out the relation between d and k. If you're dealing with numbers that go from 0 up to the number U, then the number of base-k digits in each number will be Θ(log<sub>k</sub> U) = Θ(log U / log k). This means that the runtime is more properly O(log U (n + k) / log k).

In your case, k is very small compared to n, so this runtime will have the for O(n log U / log k).

Your claim that the runtimes would be Θ(8(10 + 20,000,000)) and Θ(3(1,000 + 20,000,000)) are a bit odd. Remember that Θ notation talks about long-term growth rates rather than individual values, so it's not meaningful to plug in values this way. However, your basic argument is correct. Going from base 10 to base 10000 is a 3-fold increase in the order of magnitude of the base, so you should expect the algorithm to be roughly three times faster with the larger base.

That said, there are a lot of other factors at play that might mess up this timing in practice. Locality of reference plays a huge factor in the runtime of algorithms that do a lot of array manipulations, and as you increase the number of buckets, you get progressively worse locality. This might actually end up making the larger-base sort slower than the smaller-base sort since even though there are fewer rounds, each round takes longer due to caching effects. Without having tried this, I'd wager that there's a good chance that this is what would happen in practice.